# Configuring onSubscriptionData for React Apollo subscription client

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo

I've built a React app that is connected to a Graphql server. It is working great. The client is configured to receive real-time subscriptions. All good.

Now I want to configure my React component to use react-appollo's onSubscriptionData feature so that I do extra processing once the component receives subscription data.

I found this documentation which I think will let me achieve this: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo.html#subscription

However, I'm unsure of how to implement it. Here's what I've tried:

```
class LabSession extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.subscribeToUpdatedLabSession();
  }

  render() {
    const { lab } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        {lab && <div className="lab-detail">

        </div>}
      </div>
    )
  }

}

const LabSessionWithData = graphql(
  getLabSession,
  {
    options: props => ({
      variables: { id: props.lsid },
      fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
    }),
    props: props => ({
      lab: props.data.getLabSession ? props.data.getLabSession : [],
      subscribeToUpdatedLabSession: params => {
        props.data.subscribeToMore({
          document: updatedLabSessionSubscription,
          variables: { LabSessionID: props.ownProps.LabSessionID },
          updateQuery: (prev, { subscriptionData: { data: { onUpdateLabSession }, variables } }) => {
            return {
              ...prev,
              getLabSession: onUpdateLabSession
            }
          }
        })
      },
      onSubscriptionData: () => {
        console.log('hi dudes')
      }
    })
  },
)(LabSession);

export default LabSessionWithData;
```

Any guidance on how to properly use `onSubscriptionData` would be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: why don't you just use subscribeToMore I don't think you need onsubscriptiondata at all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think
`onSubscriptionData`
ever exposed directly to query. According to their document its `<Subscription>` prop

```
<Subscription
  subscription={subscription}
  onSubscriptionData={opts => {
    console.log("ApolloClient", opts.client);
    console.log("subscriptionData", opts.subscriptionData);
  }}
/>
```

you should use subscription in this way to get data in onSubscriptionData callback.

I would suggest to check [git demo](https://github.com/logisticinfotech/nodejs-graphql-subscription-reactjs-demo) you might get some better idea.